# Return a PartialView from $.Ajax Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following code;

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/jQueryAddComment",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: json,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(data){ 
                //var message = data.Message; 
                alert(data);
                $('.CommentSection').html(data);
            }
```

And in my controller;

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult jQueryAddComment(Comment comment)
    {
        CommentSection commentSection = new CommentSection();

        //ya da - ya da 
        // fill the commentsection object with data

        //then
        return PartialView("CommentSection", commentSection);

    }
```

However, when I get back to the page the success alert doesn't happen.  Can anyone see the flaw in this logic?

Comment: What is the current response to the post?  Check the response with Firebug and/or Fiddler.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your expecting `JSON` in the `.Ajax POST`, but in the ActionMethod your returning a `PartialView`?

Try:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Home/jQueryAddComment",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   data: json,
   success: function(data){ 
      //var message = data.Message; 
      alert(data);
      $('.CommentSection').html(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point.  I returned a json object but then data.message was null

Comment: Yeah looks like you may just be returning html and the Javascript is expecting a `JSON Object`...

Comment: If I return Json and then alert this window.alert(data) I get Object.  So how do I now get the html within the object.

Comment: Just re-read your answer and the datatype was the problme.  thanks

Comment: You have to change `dataType:json` to `dataType:"html"` in your script as what your returning from the `ActionMethod` is HTML not a `JSON Object`

Comment: i made the incorrect assumption that it was what i was passing to my controller.

Comment: I also made assumptions when I was answering your question the first time. It's human nature...

Answer (score 1):

Unless it was copied over wrong it appears you are missing some closing tokens.

```
       $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/jQueryAddComment",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data){ 
            //var message = data.Message; 
            alert(data);
            $('.CommentSection').html(data);
            } //<-- added close for anonymous function
        }); //<--added close/semicolon for ajax function
```

Also, you are POSTing but it your action doesn't appear to have the [Post] attribute.  When you run this in the debugger does a breakpoint on your action get hit?

Comment: Sorry, the closing tokens are correct, i simply didn't copy the whole function

Comment: Does a breakpoint on `jQueryAddComment` get hit in the debugger?