# View not returned properly in ASP.NET MVC Core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

On click of the button, a javascript function is called that captures the snapshot from the camera and sends it to process. On backed, we get the image and do some process and get the data in an object called "doc". Upto here the system works fine, but the data that I got in "doc" object doesn't seem to be printed on the page.

Here's the button

```
<input type="button" value="Capture Snapshot" onClick="CaptureSnapshot()">
```

And here's the javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function CaptureSnapshot() {           
        Webcam.snap(function (data) {
            // display results in page
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<img src="' + data + '"/>';
            // Send image data to the controller to store locally or in database
            Webcam.upload(data,
                '/Home/UploadFile',
                function (code, text) {
                    Webcam.reset();
                    //alert('Snapshot/Image captured successfully...');
                });
        });
    }
</script>
```

And this is the C# method written in the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
        {
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var uploadedFile in files)
                {
                    if (uploadedFile.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = uploadedFile.FileName;

                        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", fileName);
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UploadedFile", fileName);

                        byte[] imageBytes = ConvertToBytes(uploadedFile);

                        Document doc = ProcessDocumentImage(imageBytes);

                        ViewData["Document"] = doc;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                return Content("file not selected");

            return View("Index", "Home");
        }
```

If I put a breakpoint on "doc", I get the data but it doesn't go on the page. What I found is that the page is not submitted at all, maybe this is the reason.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: You are mixing things. You need to return partial view from the method and get that in javascript call and append that to a DOM element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490059/return-a-partialview-from-ajax-post Follow this thread.

Comment: Will it work when my form doesn't potback?

Comment: `return View("Index", "Home");` Your code seems to try to redirect the view to `localhost:xxx/home/index` but there's only `public virtual ViewResult View(string? viewName, object? model)` in View constructure. So you may try to use `return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");`

Comment: When I use return RedirectToAction("index", "Home"); the control doesn't go to the page. When I use return View("Index", "Home"); it goes to the page and I can see the data with breakpoint but it doesn't appear.
[main]
 <div class="input-group mb-3 px-2 py-2 bg-white shadow-sm">                   
       Status => @status <br>
 </div>
[/main]